# Norm of the Resolvent when an equality holds?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

Let X is Banach space and $T:X \rightarrow X$ is linear operator,

then 
$||R_\lambda(T)||≥\frac{1}{d(\lambda,σ(T))}\;\;\;$ where $\;\;\;R_\lambda(T) = (T-\lambda I)^{-1}$.

I would like to know when the equality holds.

In other words: what assumptions on operator $\;T\;$ I need for

$||R_\lambda(T)||=\frac{1}{d(\lambda,σ(T))}$.

Comment: Multiples if the identity work, diagonal matrices in $\mathbb R^{n,n}$ work as well.

Comment: Thx for answer. But I would like to know sufficient and necessary condition - in general.

For example, if equality holds for a closed operator, self-adjoint operator, etc.
+I am mostly interested in infinite dimensional Banach spaces